# Blank screen when connecting via Remote Desktop to Xubuntu 18.04 (hosted with Hyper-V)

Tags: xubuntu, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I installed Xubuntu 18.04 on Hyper-V.

When I want to ghost machine with Remote Desktop, it shows a blank screen.

I configured XRDP with several guides like:

https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11868

https://medium.com/@vivekteega/how-to-setup-an-xrdp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-89f7e205bd4e

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp

[Connect to Ubuntu 18.04 via RDP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132295/connect-to-ubuntu-18-04-via-rdp)

But none of them works.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic, this works:

```
sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04
```

This installs a compatible xrdp package

The old version is not compatible and if you have it installed you
have to:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get -y install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

This removes the old stuff if you have it installed

**DON'T USE THE SOLUTION BELOW!!!!**

Also other answers on the internet suggest this solution that just adds another issue to your Ubuntu 18 install

Xrdp shows a blank screen with Ubuntu 18.04, Bionic Beaver

To solve this "second session" problem and allow as many sessions as you need, edit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh and add these lines before the lines that test and execute Xsession. The $HOME/.profile is not part of the solution, but is something that should be run before starting the session anyway.

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS  
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

Comment: FYI: When installing `xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04` on 18.04.05 it says: Depends: `xorg-video-abi-24` and `xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (>= 2:1.18.99.901)`

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess

If you are running **Xubuntu 18.04.2 or 18.04.3**, you might be affected by a **know issue with xRDP**...

If you have installed xrdp package manually on your system from xubuntu repository, **xorgxrdp package is not installed** because package dependencies issues...

Try to install the new xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04 package and try again

to install the package, execute the following command

> sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04

*We assume that you have already installed xrdp package on your system...*

Hope this help
till next time 
See ya