# server ubuntu xrdp connection problem

Tags: server, connection, remote, remmina

I tried to connect into my server ubuntu from a remote ubuntu pc using remmina but i suddenly encountered this connection problem. I tried using another person's server profile and it works perfectly, then i tried entering my account using their pc and same error happened. I am not the admin of the server.

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
login successful for display 10
started connecting
connection problem, giving up
some problem
```

Comment: Do not show pictures of text try and always include text in the question.

Comment: sorry, i edited the question again.

Comment: The error message was literally `some problem`? 

Comment: yes, this is exactly what is appeared on the screen right now

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly this error pop up. In the end, the reason was that the root partition `/` was full. I logged in via ssh, deleted some large files, and remmina worked as normal again.

That's probably not what caused your issue, because otherwise "another person" wouldn't have been able to connect either. Anyway, I'll leave it here for anybody who finds this thread by searching for the error message.

See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132295/connect-to-ubuntu-18-04-via-rdp) for some more possibilities, even if that person's problem was only intermittent whereas this thread seems to be about a consistent issue.